# Unable to assign materials, maybe a material property setting issue

Tags: materials

I'm unable to assign/view a new material(in this case it is "Leather_dark_brown") to an object. I think it has something to do with my material property setting, since it has no problem assigning other materials.
[image]

Comment: As material is added to the object, what makes you think it hasn't been assigned? Viewport is in Solid shading mode which won't show any materials properties, either Rendered (more accurate) or Material (less accurate) will. Also what do you mean by "assign new material"? Is "new" meant to be one additional to that already present? Or is that "Leather_Dark_Brown" material the one you mean as "new"?

Comment: "Leather_Dark_Brown" material is the "new" material. As you can tell, the material is dark brown, however the shading remains the same after I "assign". The reason I'm thinking it's a material property issue is because I can succesfully assign and VIEW the material change if I assign another material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cycles materials will display as a solid colour in the viewport, unless the [viewport shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/shading.html) is set to material or rendered.

The [material settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/materials/settings.html) include the viewport colour to use for the material.

[image: material settings]